# Group by with condition in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

```
Sample Database Table:
+-----+----------+------+-----------+
| id  | template_title  | store_id  |
+-----+----------+------+-----------+
|   1 |      TEST_TITLE | 0         |
|   2 |      TEST_TITLE | 4         |
|   3 |      TEST_TITLE | 2         |
|   4 |      TEST_ITEM  | 0         |
|   5 |      TEST_LOVE  | 0         |

+-----+-----------------+----------+
```

i try to get record by Group by `template_title` having `store_id` 0 and 4.

then i got this record

```
    +-----+----------+------+-----------+
    | id  | template_title  | store_id  |
    +-----+----------+------+-----------+
    |   1 |      TEST_TITLE | 0         |
    |   4 |      TEST_ITEM  | 0         |
    |   5 |      TEST_LOVE  | 0         |

    +-----+-----------------+----------+
```

but i need record having Group by but if there `store_id` is not 0 then it must be get record.
like i need this type of data

```
        +-----+----------+------+-----------+
        | id  | template_title  | store_id  |
        +-----+----------+------+-----------+
        |   1 |      TEST_TITLE | 4         |
        |   4 |      TEST_ITEM  | 0         |
        |   5 |      TEST_LOVE  | 0         |

        +-----+-----------------+----------+
```

means i need `TEST_TITLE` of `4` if i group by.

I meant to say i want to give **Priority** to `Store_id` if i Group by `template_title`

Comment: For `store_id` 4 why id = 1 why not the corresponding row value of id = 2 ?

Comment: You select three values: the template_title, id and store_id. As you group by template_title, you must decide which id and which store_id to select. Obviously you decided for MAX(store_id) - which answers your question already. So what id do you want to show? Why show an id at all?

Comment: I meant to say i want to give Priority to Store_id if i Group by `template_title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly a `group by`.  You want to prioritize the rows, based on business rules.  The rule appears to be select the row with 4 first, and then the one with 0.  It think the easiest way is using `union all`:

```
select id, template_title, store_id
from databasetable
where store_id = 4
union all
select id, template_title, store_id
from databasetable
where store_id = 0 and
      not exists (select 1 from template_title where store_id = 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MAX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html) to get the biggest value in the column:

```
SELECT
  id,
  template_title,
  MAX(store_id)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY template_title
```